# Facebook share the wrong OG tags for too long (also the facebook debugger)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the currect OG tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="הורים בקריות" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="הקבוצה המורחבת שלכם" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://horim04.co.il"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="no_image" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content=""/>
```

But for more than a month facebook is pulling the wronge OG tags. also when i past my site on [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fhorim04.co.il%2F).

the link to [my site](http://horim04.co.il/)

Comment: According to the debug tool, your site responds with HTTP status 403 Forbidden - you need to fix that. Go check if you have any plugins that try to detect requests by "bots" or something like that running in your system.

Comment: i don't think this is the issue. because the debug tool pulls the wrong OG tags. it pulls the OG tags of my hosting company.... i am thinking maybe it's something with the domain ?

Comment: Well then that's where it gets the 403 from. Go check (or have the hoster check), if your domain's IPv6 (AAAA) records, if they exist, point to the right address. Facebook prefers IPv6 over IPv4,

Comment: Ok i have found the problem. the server had some firewall that blocked the facebook. i disabled it and now it works !